# StyleSheet /CSS : Placing Components in React Native

Tags: css, react-native, stylesheet

I am working on a React Native App . The components are vertically center as I desire but are all aligned on the bottom and can't get them move up towards the top of the screen.

Please take a look at the layout screen (attached here).

How can I get them to move up top?

Please Note : The yellow color in the screen is to figure out how far the component's view stretches.
I could not figure out to adjust the 'yellow' view. The 'yellow' view is only suppose to consist the donut/menu button .

```
<View style={styles.container}>


                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.drawerButton} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()} >
                         <Image
                             source={menu}
                            style={{width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: 5}}
                         />
                      </TouchableOpacity>



                        <TextInput style={styles.addText} placeholder="Add New Item"/>



                            <Button style = {styles.submitButton} title = "Add" />


                       <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.pictureButton} onPress = {this.setCameraWindow}>
                            <Text style={{fontSize:14}}> Take Picture </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>


                            {this.state.isCameraVisible ? this.takePicture() : null }



                    </View>

        );
    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({

       container:{
           flex:1,
           flexDirection: 'column',
           alignItems:'center',
           flexGrow: 1,
           justifyContent: 'center',
           backgroundColor: 'blue'

       }, 

       drawerButton:{
        flex:1,
        flexDirection:'row',
        alignSelf:'flex-start',
        backgroundColor:'yellow'    
       },

        menuButton: {
            height:50,
            flex:1,
            flexDirection:'column',
            alignSelf:'flex-start',
            backgroundColor:'yellow',



        },

        addText:{

            flex:1,
            flexDirection:'column',
            justifyContent:'center',
            backgroundColor:'white',
            borderBottomColor: 'black',
            borderBottomWidth: 2,
            alignSelf:'center',
            maxHeight:50,

          },

        submitButton:{

            justifyContent:'center'
        },

        pictureButton:{
            backgroundColor:'white',
            justifyContent: 'center',

        },

});
```

Thank you[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given `flex:1` inside the `style={styles.drawerButton}`, thats why its taking up the entire space and other things are pushed to the end of the screen, please remove flex:1 from that, and also remove `justifyContent: 'center'` from container style. Then all the content will be moved to the top

Comment: Thank you for clarifying and expaling it.

Answer (score 0):

[These styles](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_mobile_navbar.asp) are what you need. Specifically:

`overflow: hidden`: Hides the yellow bit when the menu is collapsed.

`position: absolute` on the menu. This means the menu will appear in the same position regardless of the other content. Use `top: 10px; left: 10px` to control the actual positioning of the menu.

`position: relative` on the menu's *parent* (TouchableOpacity) element. This means the `position: absolute` of the menu will be relative to the parent element.

You may have to get rid of some of the other styles, at least temporarily, so you can see what is happening.